# How do I implement a unit test for a function that invokes two other functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, unit-testing, testing

Inside this module, I want to test the getAppts function, which invokes two function. What is the correct way of evaluating the code that getAppts encompasses? Do I have to run db.getDatabase() and fetchAppts() as stubs inside the unit test function? My unit test implementation is, at best, incomplete, but it could be totally wrong.

```
'use strict'

const db = require('../db/db')
const log = require('../utils/logging')(__filename)
const { fetchAppts, fetchApptDetails } = require('../db/dao/appointment-dao')

async function getAppts (queryParams) {
  log.debug('getAppts(): %j', queryParams)
  const knex = db.getDatabase()
  const appointments = await fetchAppts(queryParams, knex)
  return appointments
}

async function getApptDetails (demoApptId) {
  log.debug('getApptDetails(): %j', demoApptId)
  const knex = db.getDatabase()
  const apptDetails = await fetchApptDetails(demoApptId, knex)
  return apptDetails
}

module.exports = {
  getAppts,
  getApptDetails
}
```

unit test setup:

```
'use strict'

const sinon = require('sinon')
const chai = require('chai')
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised')
const dirtyChai = require('dirty-chai')
const sinonChai = require('sinon-chai')
const { expect } = require('chai')
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire')

const apptsResponse = require('../../data/get-appts-response.json')

chai.use(dirtyChai)
chai.use(sinonChai)
chai.use(chaiAsPromised)
chai.should()

describe.only('appointment-service.js', () => {
  let apptService
  let apptDaoStub
  let dbStub

  beforeEach(() => {
    dbStub = {
      getDatabase: sinon.stub()
    }
    apptDaoStub = {
      fetchAppts: sinon.stub()
    }
    apptService = proxyquire('../../../services/appointment-service', {
      '../db/db': dbStub,
      '../db/dao/appointment-dao': apptDaoStub
    })
  })

  afterEach(() => sinon.restore())

  describe('getAppts', () => {
    it.only('should get appointments', async () => {
      const appts = await apptService.getAppts({})
      dbStub.getDatabase.should.have.been.calledTwice
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mock functions, you will need to import the module:

```
it('should get appointments',  async () => {
  const mockFn = jest.spyOn(db, 'getDatabase');
  const appts = await apptService.getAppts({})
  expect(mockFn).toBeCalledTimes(1); // depends on how many times fn is called
});
```

You can learn more about mocking here:
https://www.chakshunyu.com/blog/how-to-mock-only-one-function-from-a-module-in-jest/

Comment: const mockFn = jest.spyOn(db, 'getDatabase')
where is db coming from?

Comment: I am assuming the name of your module is db. You have to replace db with name of your module from where you are importing the function you want to mock

Comment: apptService = proxyquire('../../../services/appointment-service', {
      '../db/db': dbStub,
      '../db/dao/appointment-dao': apptDaoStub
    })

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this comment